# css - How to centralize text vertically when there's no overflow?

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 64px;
  max-height: 288px;
  padding: 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Text goes here...</p>
</div>
```

I have this container that grows with the text up to a limit of 288px, but shrinks up to 64px when the text isn't enough to fill the container.
The problem is: I want the small text to be vertically centralized in the minimum-sized container. This css does that. But when the text overflows, it's still centralized, so part of it is hidden above the container and can't be reached.

Screenshot for reference (it is impossible to scroll up):
[screenshot of overflowing text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLh9I.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 64px;
  max-height: 288px;
  padding: 12px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.container p {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Another solution <strong>usong display:table</strong></h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Text goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p> a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
      content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
      versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin
      literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites
      of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on
      the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those
      interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Where can I get some? There are many
      variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need
      to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of
      over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc. 5 paragraphs
      words bytes lists Start with 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'
    </p>
  </div>
```

- Just ste `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to `auto`

```css
 margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 64px;
  max-height: 288px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Text goes here...</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p> a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content
    here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
    have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
    from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word
    in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of
    ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections
    1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages
    of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't
    anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined
    with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc. 5 paragraphs words bytes lists Start
    with 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Or use a span element in the <P> tags  <span class="headers"> Long Heading </span></p>